# Define ARIMA Model (p,d,q) based on parameter significance, whitenoise and normality assumptions

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, modeling, arima, diagnostic

I was following the ACF and PACF Plot but it didn't fulfill paramater significance, white noise assumption and normality assumption. So I did model identification for several times to get the model which fulfill those assumptions and didn't . and then I pick an ARIMA Seasonal model (2,1,0)(0,0,4)7 and it already fulfilled those assumptions.

As You can see, order P = 2. So it has to cut off at lag 2 in PACF plot. but in PACF lag 2 didn't cut off. Is it ok to force the model based on those assumptions? Please complete Your answer with references. Thankyou :)

Comment: If you're using R, there is this `auto.arima` function in the `forecast` package. It selects the AR, MA, and the integration order for you. No need to do any of this guess work. Beware that it may take forever to finish though (thanks to `optim` i think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> order P = 2. So it has to cut off at lag 2 in PACF plot. but in PACF lag 2 didn't cut off.

For a purely autoregressive process AR($p$), it is ACF (not PACF) that cuts off after $p$ lags. (For a reference check any time series textbook. You can also simulate some AR($p$) processes to see the phenomenon empirically.)

> Is it ok to force the model based on those assumptions?

If you find significant parameters and white-noise, normal residuals there is little more to ask. There does not seem to be a fault with the model based on the current information. However, the nice results might also be due to chance (plausible when fitting a large number of candidate models and selecting the best-fitting one). Then you would need to sample more data and examine the model performance there (estimate on the original sample, evaluate on the new sample). This way you could see whether the fit is not just spuriously good.